# what is the difference between assigning and spreading an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Recently I discovered during a challenge exercise, that:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let x = array
let y = [...array]

console.log(x, y);
```

`x` and `y` in theory look the same but apparently under the hood  they are not the same because one passes the test and the other does not.

Is there any thing that I'm missing here. Up to this point assigning and spreading where pretty much the same thing for me.

Thank you

Comment: Simple assignment does not make a *copy* of the source array; the spread assignment does.

Comment: passes what test?

Comment: but changing x won't change the array above?! right?

Comment: It will, and that's exactly the difference.

Comment: `array[0] = "A"; x[1] = "X"; y[2] = "y"; console.log(array, x, y)`

Comment: `[...array]` is basically the same as `var tempArray = []; for (var v of array) { tempArray.push(v); }; return tempArray;`.

Comment: Note that spreading also only is a shallow copy. `let array = [{ a: 0 }]; let x = [...array]; x[0].a = 1; console.log(array);` - the element in `array` will change, but e.g. `x[0] = null;` won't do anything to `array`.

Comment: gotcha... great examples !! thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let x = array;` just makes the `x` variable and the `array` variable both point to the **same** array:

```
array−−−+
        |    +−−−−−−−−−+
        +−−−>| (array) |
        |    +−−−−−−−−−+
x−−−−−−−+    | 0: 1    |
             | 1: 2    |
             | 2: 3    |
             | 3: 4    |
             | 4: 5    |
             +−−−−−−−−−+
```

`let y = [...array];` creates a **new** array and copies all of the entries from `array` into it.

```
             +−−−−−−−−−+
array−−−−−−−>| (array) |
             +−−−−−−−−−+
             | 0: 1    |
             | 1: 2    |
             | 2: 3    |
             | 3: 4    |
             | 4: 5    |
             +−−−−−−−−−+

             +−−−−−−−−−+
y−−−−−−−−−−−>| (array) |
             +−−−−−−−−−+
             | 0: 1    |
             | 1: 2    |
             | 2: 3    |
             | 3: 4    |
             | 4: 5    |
             +−−−−−−−−−+
```

Since arrays are mutable (you can change their state), this is important because if you're going to make changes and didn't want to change the original array, you want the second (or similar), not the first.

---

It's probably worth noting that `let y = [...array];` also creates an array even if `array` isn't one, as long as it's *iterable*, because any iterable can be spread that way. For instance, `let y = [..."foo"];` creates an array like this: `["f", "o", "o"]` because strings are iterable.

Answer (score 2):

when using the assignment operator you don't create a coppy of the array, instead you create a coppy of the reference to the same array so if you change x , the original array will change too..but with the spread operator they are separate arrays so they don't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

The difference has to do with how Objects are referenced in Javascript.

While simple (scalar) types like number and string are copied each time they're referenced, Objects (Arrays inherit from Object) are passed by reference.

[This article seems to explain that well enough](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

So in your code, when spreading your array into brackets you are instantiating a new array, and receive a pointer to a different Object.

Comment: They are not passed *by* reference, they are reference-type values, so one could say they are passed *as* reference. Pass-by-reference refers to a very specific behavior that JavaScript does not do.

Comment: Pass by reference means you can do something like this: `var x = 42; var y = x; x = 21; // y is 21 as well`. That's not how JavaScript works whether we deal with value-type values or reference-type values. It's a single word but it makes a big difference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference